# writing in file using threads (WINAPI)

Tags: c, multithreading, file, winapi, mutex

Just when I thought I finally understood threads, I got a problem.

In the main thread, I create a mutex using this:

```cpp
Mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, Mutex_Name);
```

Then, in one of the worker threads (the first one to reach), I have a function that returns a handle to a file by creating it like this:

```cpp
file_h = CreateFile("The_File.txt",
                    GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
                    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                    NULL,
                    CREATE_NEW,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    NULL);
```

The other threads have functions that return a handle to the file by this:

```cpp
file_h = CreateFile("The_File.txt",
                    GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
                    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                    NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    NULL);
```

At the last part, both threads try to write to the file using this function:

```cpp
int W_to_f(char* str_to_w, HANDLE file)
{
    HANDLE mutex = NULL;
    DWORD waitcode1;
    DWORD dwBytesWrite;
    char line[Line_Len];
    mutex = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, LOCK);
    if (mutex == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed at opening LOCK in write file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    waitcode1 = WaitForSingleObject(mutex, 15000);
    if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != waitcode1)
    {
        printf("Error when waiting for LOCK in file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(line, str_to_w);
    while ((Line_Len - (strlen(line) + 1)) > 0)
    {
        strcat(line, "@");
    }
    SetFilePointer(file, 0, NULL, FILE_END); //problem?
    WriteFile(file, line, strlen(line), &dwBytesWrite, NULL);
    WriteFile(file, "\n", 2, &dwBytesWrite, NULL);
    if(!ReleaseMutex(mutex))
    {
        printf("failed release mutex in write_file fun\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

All I want them to do is to write to the file like this:

```
firststring@@@@@@@@@@@@
secondstring@@@@@@@@@@@
```

But, after checking with breakpoints, what I get is that the first one manages to write to file:

```
firststring@@@@@@@@@@@
```

But then after the second one writes to the file, it becomes:

```
癡慩㩤㈱㐳䁀䁀䁀䁀䁀䁀䁀䁀䁀幀搀湩楤㩮㘵㠷䁀䁀䁀䁀䁀䁀䁀䁀䁀
```

Just one line, it doesn't even write the Chinese after the `firststring@@@@`.

Should I somehow use `SetFilePointer`?

Should I `CreateFile()` in the function using `OPEN_EXISTING` for each thread?

Comment: Can you please extract a [mcve] and include that in your question? As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You should use a single file handle and serialize writing to the file. Then you wouldn't need to use that dangerous share mode. And you could the the filer pointer take care of itself.

Comment: `W_to_f()` is leaking the `HANDLE` returned by `OpenMutex()`. You need to call `CloseHandle()` when you are done using it. But, you really should not be using `OpenMutex()` every time the function is called. You should share the `HANDLE` returned by `CreateMutex()` with all of your threads instead. And why are you giving the mutex a name, and marking it for inheritance? Are you planning on writing to the same file across process boundaries? In any case, your `strcpy()` has a potenital buffer overflow. And `WriteFile("\n", 2)` should be `WriteFile("\n", 1)` or `WriteFile("\r\n", 2)` instead.

Comment: I think the problem is that you write an extra byte each time when you call `WriteFile("\n", 2)`, which resulted in garbled characters after I tested it. And you can determine by getting the return value of `SetFilePointer` Whether to locate the location you want.